# Big-Oh notation and finding appropriate c and n0

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I looked up other questions regarding asymptotic notations but none of them are similar to this.

Here is the equation given:

`10 n^3 + 15 n^4 + 100 n^2 x 2^n = O(n^2 x 2^n)`
I need to find the appropriate c and n0.
What I have done so far:

`10 n/2^n + 15 n^2/2^n + 100 <= c   (Dividing by dominant after writing the definition of Big - Oh)`

After finding the maxima of `10 n/2^n + 15 n^2/2^n` by differentiating wrt n (overkill?) and found that n = 3

And the required constant c=121 after plugging in n = 3 in the above equation.

Whatever I have done, is it correct?

Also, would it be wrong to claim an answer of c=125 and n0=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `n > 0` (`nk` is notation for `n^k` for the sake of readability)

```
10n3 + 15n4 + 100n2 2^n <= c n2 2^n
<=> 10n3 + 15n4 <= (c - 100) n2 2^n
<=> 10n + 15n2 <= (c - 100) 2^n
<=> c >= (10n + 15n2) / 2^n + 100
```

Replace `n` with desired `n0 >= argmax((10n + 15n2) / 2^n + 100)` here. *e.g.* with `n0 = 3`

```
c >= (10 * 3 + 15 * 3^2) / 2^3 + 100 = 120.625
```

Comment: Wont the value of c fail when n=2 ?:

```LHS: 10x8 + 15x16 + 100 x4x4=1920. ```

```RHS: 112.5 x 4 x 4 =1800```

Comment: indeed you're right, chose any `n0` past `argmax((10n + 15n2) / 2^n + 100)`, which is around `n ~= 2.59`. I edited my answer.

Comment: So what I've done is correct, right? I am asking this because I think I've finally understood what these notations mean and just want to confirm. Thank you, by the way.